# iOS objective c uploading csv file to ftp server

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm using iOS simpleFTP example as a guide to upload a file to my ftp server (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html).  The file locally contains the data but after my app uploads the file on my ftp server it shows up empty (0 bytes).  Can anyone see in my code why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
    NSString *resultLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",
                            aField.text, bField.text, cField.text];

    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *csvFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.csv",aField.text];

    NSString *reportsCSV = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:csvFileName];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:reportsCSV])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:reportsCSV error:NULL];
    } else{
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:reportsCSV contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:reportsCSV];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[resultLine dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:reportsCSV])
    {
        NSLog(@"File report type CSV: %@", reportsCSV);
        if ( ! self.isSending ) {
            [self startSend:reportsCSV];
        }

    }
```

The startSend method:

```
    - (void)startSend:(NSString *)filePath
{
BOOL                    success;
NSURL *                 url;

assert(filePath != nil);
//assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
//assert( [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"png"] || [filePath.pathExtension isEqual:@"jpg"] );

assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap send twice in a row!
assert(self.fileStream == nil);         // ditto

// First get and check the URL.

url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:@"ftp.fooftp.com"];
success = (url != nil);

if (success) {
    // Add the last part of the file name to the end of the URL to form the final 
    // URL that we're going to put to.

    url = CFBridgingRelease(
                            CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) [filePath lastPathComponent], false)
                            );
    success = (url != nil);
}

// If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

if ( ! success) {
    self.sendingLabel.text = @"Invalid URL";
} else {

    // Open a stream for the file we're going to send.  We do not open this stream; 
    // NSURLConnection will do it for us.

    self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];
    assert(self.fileStream != nil);

    [self.fileStream open];

    // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.

    self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                           CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                           );
    assert(self.networkStream != nil);


        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"user" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
        assert(success);
        success = [self.networkStream setProperty:@"pass" forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
        assert(success);

    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.networkStream open];

    // Tell the UI we're sending.

    [self sendDidStart];
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend to use existing frameworks to work with internet requests: RestKit, AFNetworking and etc

Comment: You can also use NSUrlConnection - it knows FTP too. All very high level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation, but with txt files and image files... 
I have a class for upload the files, this class is based in the view controller example, and too have the view controller from the sample in the same project, with the class the uploaded files are empty (0 bytes) but this not occur with the view controller, this upload the files correctly...